# Why are strings from sys.stdin different from hardcoded strings in my script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does the following print "False"?

test.py:

```
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for text in sys.stdin:
        text_in_script = 'test'

        print(text == text_in_script)
```

Command line:

```
echo test | py -3 test.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `sys.stdin` texts come with a new line character. It is more obvious when test.py is this:

```
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for text in sys.stdin:
        text_in_script = 'test'

        print("Input:  {}".format(text))
        print("Script: {}".format(text_in_script))
        print(text == text_in_script)
```

The solution would be to strip the new line character. The following will return "True":

```
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for text in sys.stdin:
        text_in_script = 'test'

        # warning: rstrip() removes all whitespace; see rstrip() docs for alternatives
        print(text.rstrip() == text_in_script)
```

Comment: Updated question and answer.

Comment: If trailing whitespace might be important then use `line.rstrip("\n")` instead  (note: it is portable if Python uses universal newlines mode (it does by default))